# ValueError: X has 4 features per sample; expecting 32

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am having a little challenge here. The following code is returning a Valueerror when running `ValueError: X has 4 features per sample; expecting 32`

Not sure why as I already looked at the other topics related to that matter. I checked my df frame size which is indeed 1x4 (which matches the number of inputs given to the model). I am also saving the model into a separate file with pickle to avoid any matter as usually recommended.

Still, that does not seem to work. Would you have any idea on how to fix that? I am clueless regarding the origin of the error here.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import linear_model

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


import pickle


df_raw = pd.read_csv('\\Users\\rapha\\Desktop\\Consulting\\Poker\\Tables test\\Final model\\Regressions DONE\SB Allpro DB - a1_preflop flag1 & 2 & 3 V1.csv', sep=";")




#Select categorical features only & use binary encoding

feature_cols1 = ['tiers','score','proba_preflop','proba2_preflop','action1_preflop']



df_raw = df_raw[feature_cols1]
df_backup = df_raw['action1_preflop']
cat_features = df_raw.select_dtypes(include=[object])

num_features = df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
num_features = num_features.drop(['action1_preflop'], axis=1)
df = num_features.join(pd.get_dummies(cat_features))
df = df.join(df_backup)



df_outcome = df.action1_preflop
df_variables_mid = df.drop('action1_preflop',axis=1)


col_names = list(df_variables_mid.columns)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_variables_minmax = scaler.fit_transform(df_variables_mid)
df_variables = pd.DataFrame(df_variables_minmax,columns = col_names)

x = df_variables
y = df.action1_preflop


x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

lm = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='saga', max_iter=1000)




lm.fit(x_train, y_train)


filename = 'SBmodel_preflop_a1.sav'
pickle.dump(lm, open(filename, 'wb'))
 
# some time later...
 
# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(x_test, y_test)





pred_cols1 = ['tiers','score','proba_preflop','proba2_preflop']

df_pred = pd.DataFrame(columns= pred_cols1)

df_pred.loc[1] = pd.Series({'tiers':'tiers4', 'score':'score2', 'proba_preflop':0.2224, 'proba2_preflop':3})


cat_features = df_pred.select_dtypes(include=[object])
num_features = df_pred.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
df_pred = num_features.join(pd.get_dummies(cat_features))


result = loaded_model.predict(df_pred)
```

Below is the traceback

```
  File "C:\Users\rapha\Desktop\Consulting\Poker\Tables test\Final model\Regressions DONE\Logreg_SB_preflop_a1 DONE V1.py", line 83, in <module>
    result = loaded_model.predict(df_pred)

  File "C:\Users\rapha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 293, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)

  File "C:\Users\rapha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 273, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))

ValueError: X has 4 features per sample; expecting 32
```

Comment: which line gave you this error?

Comment: I've just added the traceback to the initial post

Comment: please post: x.shape and y.shape

Comment: x_test is (3018, 32), y_test is (3018,) and df_pred (the input I want to use to make a prediction) is (1, 4).

Note that x_test & y_test shape are not causing any issue. The issue comes from the very last line of the script that uses loaded_model.predict(df_pred), otherwise the rest does not create any error

Comment: The error is saying that "you fit a model with 32 features, and are trying to predict using an example with 4 features." The `df_pred` would need to be `(1, 32)` at least. It looks like some preprocessing is performed before fitting the model—these steps would also need to be applied to any new examples if the raw data looked like `(1, 4)`.

Comment: Yes we could say that. But the difference between the (1,32) and (1,4) shape comes from the categorical value encoding. Considering that my training dataset has multiple categorical values, it creates a higher number of encoded columns than the last dataframe on which I want to predict something.

But I'm not sure how I should handle this matter?

Comment: Yes **we do say that**. This is a fundamental concept in machine learning: we have an `NxM` matrix of `N` variables and we want to minimize the loss when predicting the values in a `1xM` vector. If some of those variables are ordinal or categorical, we usually fit a [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) before training, then apply it before testing in order to ensure the matrices have a consistent set of `N` variables in each step.